How can I use testnet4 with Bitcoin Core today?
As of June 2024, testnet3 is being attacked by block storm. It is borderline unuseable for a development environment.
I'd like to try testnet4.
How should I configure Bitcoin Core to connect to the right chain?
Also looking for some faucets to get started.
Thank you very much!

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/124447/145623 There is an answer to how to configure

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/124447/145623
There is an answer on how to configure. Recently I had same question
Pieter Wuille said:
You can set Bitcoin Core to run in testnet4 mode by putting chain=testnet4 or testnet4=1 in the configuration, or by using equivalent command-line options (-chain=testnet4 or -testnet4).
This is contrasted with the options available for testnet3: chain=test, or chain=testnet, or testnet=1 (and equivalent command-line options -chain=test, -chain=testnet, or -testnet).
